# php exec() replacment maybe with proc_open()

Tags: php

Hi by using the `exec()` command like this

```
$cmd = "php -q nah.php some args";
echo `$cmd`;
echo "lalal";
```

But if the php file doesn't have access to `exec()` cmd and somehow I find that using `exec()` isn't safe.

Replacements I could find were `popen()` and `proc_open()`

I could do this in `popen()` without arguments but I also want to pass some arguments(variable) to the file.

How can I do this - provoke a file and pass arguments(variable) together ?

Comment: when safe_mode is on you can't use command line functon like exec, popen.proc_open ... and no way is to use that!

Comment: @hamid opps wrong title try read the question completely

Comment: what are you trying to achieve that needs system commands?

Comment: Hmmm!what do you want to do exactly ?why did you use command line ? why didn't use CURL or something like this ?

Comment: @hamid How do i use cURL in this case ?

Comment: Could you say me what do you wanna do by your file ?If i know what do you want to reach i can help you efficiently!

Comment: @hamid The new file should have access to read file , pass query to mysql database and bla bla. Almost anything i think i know in php in CLI

Comment: and if it can write output i will prefer that way

Answer (score 0):

```
//   foo.php

    function foo(){

     $var1 = $_GET['var1'];
     $var2 = $_GET['var2']

     //do something by variables



    } 

// bar.php

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "foo.php?var1=XXXXXX&var2=XXXXXXXX"); 

    //Also you could send your variables by post 
    //$data = array('var1' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'var2' => 'XXXXXXXXX');
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'foo.php');
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $output;
```

**EDIT**

Use this

```
    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'var1' => 'some content',
            'var2' => 'doh'
        )
    );
    // If use POST 
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => $postdata
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $file = file_get_contents('foo.php', false, $context);   

    // USE GET 
   $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'GET',
            'header'=>"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $file = file_get_contents('foo.php?'.$data, false, $context); 

    echo $file;
```

Comment: As i havent used cURL. Can u explain a bit to me lol. I know i am being idiotic :P

Comment: And aslo gives an error:
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/pbot/test1.php on line 2

Comment: So always CURL used to get remote file!you use command line to run your file and i suggest you use curl instead of it but i don't know what's your code and why did you use command line!?but when anyone use command line to run a file and it's not possible i suugest use curl!

Comment: 5.3.2 And now after i gave me an error i downloaded cURL and still it doesnt shows CURL in phpinfo() =.=

Comment: I know that's y i am amazed :O

Comment: Gives an html error page in CLI but when i try it on browser returns nothing GAH

Comment: because you send variable by post and you wanna get those by get!I edited it retry it!

Comment: LOL u know what it echoes is :
<?php

     $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
     $var2 = $_POST['var2']

 echo $var1 . "\n" . $var2;
 
?>
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: data in /var/www/pbot/test1.php on line 29
<?php

     $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
     $var2 = $_POST['var2']

 echo $var1 . "\n" . $var2;
 
?>

Nvm u tried ur best :D

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the command line arguments are simply part of the command, so they go in the first parameter, just like any other program execution function.